# No se estilizar el select para que quede como en la foto solamente con html y css

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]adjunto el resultado de como quiero que quede. Lo tengo todo salvo el dar ese style personalizado a los "select" que no tengo ni idea de como lograrlo.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;       
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    font:16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

.container {
    width: 90%;        
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}

h1{
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

form{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}

fieldset{
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

legend{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #2e4482;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

.label-linia label, .label-linia p+ul li{
    display: inline;
}

textarea {
    display: block;
}

input, select, textarea{
    padding: 0.9em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus{
    background-color: #dce3f8;
}

#nom, #cognom, #correu, #direccio, textarea{
    width: 70%;
}

#poblacio,  #postal{
    width: 30%;
}

#telefon, #dia, #any{
    width: 15%;
}

input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]{
    background-color: #5882fa;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label span {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #5882fa;
}

div p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

footer{
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

footer p:first-child{
    float: left;
}

footer p:nth-child(2){
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ca">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Formulari de sol·licitud de novetats</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Formularios en HTML5 y CSS3">
    <!--<meta name="keywords" content="programación, programar, educación, aprendizaje, online, codeacademy">-->
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Titular del documento -->
        <h1>El formulari: sol·licitud d'enviament de novetats</h1>

        <!-- Declaración del formulario -->
        <form name="enviament" method="POST" action="#">
            <!-- Agrupación de elementos -->
            <fieldset> 
                <legend>Dades bàsiques d'identificació personal</legend>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="nom">Nom <span>(obligatori)</span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="nom" required="required" name="nom" value="" placeholder="Escrigui el seu nom">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="cognom">Cognoms <span>(obligatori)</span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="cognom" required="required" name="cognom" value="">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="correu">Correu electrònic <span class="obligatori">(obligatori)</span></label>
                        <input type="email" id="correu" required="required" name="correu" value="">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="direccio">Adreça <span>(obligatori)</span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="direccio" required="required" name="direccio" value=""> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="poblacio">Població <span>(obligatori)</span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="poblacio" required="required" name="poblacio" value="">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="postal">Codi Postal <span>(obligatori)</span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="postal" required="required" name="postal" value="">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>

            <!-- Agrupació de entradas -->
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Altres dades personals</legend>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="sexe">Sexe</label>
                        <select name="sexe" id="sexe">
                            <option value="" selected>Seleccioneu una opció</option>
                            <option value="masculi">Masculí</option>
                            <option value="femeni">Femení</option>
                            <option value="undefined">Sin definir</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Data de naixement</label> <!-- Label implícito -->
                        <input type="text" id="dia" name="dia" value="Dia de naixement">
                        <select name="mes">
                            <option value="" selected>Seleccioneu un mes</option>
                            <option value="1">Gener</option>
                            <option value="2">Febrer</option>
                            <option value="3">Març</option>
                            <option value="4">Abril</option>
                            <option value="5">Maig</option>
                            <option value="6">Juny</option>
                            <option value="7">Juliol</option>
                            <option value="8">Agost</option>
                            <option value="9">Setembre</option>
                            <option value="10">Octubre</option>
                            <option value="11">Novembre</option>
                            <option value="12">Desembre</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" id="any" name="any" value="" placeholder="Any de naixement">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="telefon">Telèfon mòvil</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="telefon" name="telefon" value="">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>

            <!-- Agrupación de entradas -->
            <fieldset class="label-linia">
                <legend>Tipus de dades que us interessen</legend>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="i1" id="serveis" value="serveis">
                        <label for="serveis">Serveis</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="i2" id="demografiques" value="demografiques">
                        <label for="demografiques">Demogràfiques</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="i3" id="societat" value="societat">
                        <label for="societat">Societat</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="i4" id="economia" value="economia">
                        <label for="economia">Economia</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="i5" id="medi-ambient" value="medi">
                        <label for="medi">Medi ambient</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="i6" id="territori" value="territori">
                        <label for="territori">Territori</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="altres-temes">Indiqueu altres tipus de dades que no trobeu en el llistat anterior</label>
                        <textarea id="altres-temes" id="altres-temes"></textarea>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="label-linia">
                <legend>Publicacions</legend>
                <p> Si esteu interessat a rebre els nostres anuals estadístics, indiqueu la forma en què voldreu fer efectiu el pagament:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="pagament" id="contra-reembossament" value="contra-reembossament">
                        <label for="contra-reembossament">Contra-reembossament</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="pagament" id="transferencia" value="transferencia">
                        <label for="transferencia">Transferència bancària</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>

            <div>
                <p>En fer clic a "Envia" manifesteu haver llegit i acceptat expressament la nostra política de protecció de dades</p>
            </div>

            <!-- Botons d'enviar i netejar -->
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Envia la teva sol·licitud">
                <input type="reset" value="Neteja les dades">
            </div>
        </form>

        <footer>
            <p>Formularis</p>
            <p>Curs de disseny i publicació de Pàgines Web</p>
        </footer>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con la misma dinámica de los input? Es decir: select[name="mes"], así buscas todos los select que tengan el atributo name = mes, y así con todos, ¿o es que directamente no te selecciona los select?

Comment: mira la foto que he actualizado lo he marcado con flechitas que es lo que necesito

Comment: Por eso, prueba a poner esto a ver, si se marca en lima:
select[name="mes"]{background-color:lime;}

Si se marca en lima, es que ya puedes trabajar con ese comando, sino, habrá que probar otras cosas a ver

Comment: Tienes la fuente de donde has sacado la foto? Si es un select o solo unos elementos personalizados que actúan como select.

Comment: El tema es que en los select sin tener que entrar en ninguno salga ese color en vertical esa especie de azul claro - oscuro.

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es algo como esto: https://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/VYMeXp (sacado de esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153080/how-do-i-change-the-select-box-arrow). La idea es utilizar el `-webkit-appearance: none;` para quitar los estilos y luego usar `linear-gradients` para crear la flecha y el fondo. Requiere un poco de "ingeniería" pero funciona bien.

Comment: Gracias es justo lo que necesitaba como pongo para que me has respondido la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es algo como esto: [codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/VYMeXp](http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/VYMeXp) (sacado de esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153080/how-do-i-change-the-select-box-arrow.

La idea es utilizar el `-webkit-appearance: none;` para quitar los estilos y luego usar `linear-gradients` para crear la flecha y el fondo.

Requiere un poco de "ingeniería" pero funciona bien.

Comment: Gracias Amilcar diste con la respuesta q necesitaba mañana te entregaré los 100 puntos de bonificación.